# How can i delete selected data in TextBox from Database on the button click event in Android?

Tags: java, android, database

I have an `EditText` and a `Button` in my Android application. When I entered the values in the `EditText`, the values were stored in a database. Now I want to delete these values from the batabase on the `Button`'s click event. How can I do this?

How can I delete the record?

Thanks in advance..

Here is my code what I am doing:-

```
btn2.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(View v){  

            String value = ((TextView) output).getText().toString();
            if(dh.equals(value))
            {
                   dh.delete(value);
                   dh.selectAll();
            }


      }

}));
```

}

Comment: What's dh? Show us the code that stores the values to database.

Comment: @Egor:when i first looked at the comment(without seeing the above code), I got (What's dh) What's the hell. lolz

Answer (score 0):

You should create database connectivity and then you should write proper query inside onClick(View v) which will delete the record from database.